# CDI within Jboss AS7 Module

Tags: java, jboss, cdi

I am have and jar which I am deploying as JBoss Module and want to send message to JMS queue.
I tried to do CDI for JMS queue but no success.

I already  tried to put all needed dependancy but nothing worked.
here is my module.xml

```
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.abc.xyz">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="myModule.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.hornetq"/>
    <module name="javax.inject.api"/>   
    <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.ejb.api"/>
    <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
    <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
    <module name="javax.interceptor.api"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.as.weld"/>  
    <module name="javax.xml.stream.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

I want to know if it is possible what I am trying to do? And if yes then how :)

Comment: Did you add a beans.xml to the jar? Otherwise JBoss is not going to initialize CDI for that module.

Comment: Yes I have beans.xml under META-INF directory

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to your deployment Structure XML or module dependency where you try to access your module

```
<dependencies>
   <module name="org.mymodule" export="true" meta-inf="import"/>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: This works if you're on EAP 6.1 or JBoss AS 7.2 or higher.  It will not work in 7.1.x, this is not possible in those versions.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification ... I use EAP6.1 and didn't check otherwise.

Comment: @JanGalinski, let me explain more. the module is a log-handler and  no component is having it as dependency. it just when anyone do logger.log() my jboss module intercept it and send the message to JMS queue. So adding deployment structure will not work.